# How to import *.xml code style into Webstorm IDE?

Tags: ide, coding-style, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am setting up my local workspace at the moment and I was wondering whether I could use the code styles found here (https://github.com/google/styleguide) inside my Webstorm IDE.

When trying to import code styles Webstorm asks for JSCS config files. I have no idea what they are.

Is there a way to import the *.xml-files as code styles?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to import arbitrary XML as a new code style in WebStorm. WebStorm stores its own code style settings in .xml files, but format is different from the one used in https://github.com/google/styleguide. So no, there is no way to import these style guides in WebStorm.
Starting from version 11, WebStorm supports importing a subset of code style options from [JSCS](http://jscs.info/) - see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/08/maintaining-consistent-code-style/